# Unable to connect to MySQL through PHP script when using mysqli or PDO BUT mysql works

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, mysql-error-2003

I am facing a weird situation. When I am trying to connect to MySql database using a "mysql" connection, it works.

```
mysql connection string -> mysql_connect($HOST, $USER, $PASSWORD, $DB);
```

But the connection fails immediately fails when I use either "mysqli" or "PDO"

```
mysqli connection string -> mysqli_connect($HOST, $USER, $PASSWORD, $DB); 
PDO Connection string -> new PDO("mysql:host=$HOST;dbname=$DB", $USER, $PASSWORD);
```

The specific error that it throws is,

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061
```

Can you guys help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Guess: check if it's installed.

Comment: Yes all of them are installed. I get a proper PDOException when PDO Connection strin fails. Same goes for mysqli.

Answer (score 5):

I've run into this from time to time.  The explanation is most often that MySQL Server is configured to use a socket file at one path, but `php.ini`'s section on mysqli or pdo_mysql is looking for the socket file at another path.

This happens to me even though I install both PHP and MySQL from MacPorts.  You'd think they'd have made the configurations for these two ports agree.

Either edit your `php.ini` to set the correct location of the socket file, or else specify the socket when you initiate a connection with mysqli or pdo_mysql.

```
pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=test;unix_socket=/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock", 
  "username", "password")

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "test",
  ini_get("mysqli.default_port"), "/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock")
```

See also the article I wrote [*Error2003-CantConnectToMySQLServer*](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Error2003-CantConnectToMySQLServer).

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but it does not work. Mainly because I do not know where the socket file is. Also I am on a Windows Box. One other thing I forgot to mention was that my apache instance is running from a Portable Server (Server2Go). Would this make any difference?

Comment: Oh, if it's Windows, then the socket idea is irrelevant.  That only applies on UNIX/Linux.

Comment: This worked for us. In our case we have mysqli.default_socket already set, so I substituted that in the ini_get and it worked great.