# MySQLi won't authenticate with localhost, but MySQL_connect will

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am upgrading a server from vulnerable `mysql_*` functions to better `$mysqli->` functions, but I've run into a problem at the very beginning. I have something like this:

```
$host = "localhost";
$u = "user";
$p = "pass";
$db = "database";
```

The old connection protocol looks like this:

```
$link = mysql_connect($host, $u, $p);
if(!$link){die();}
mysql_select_db($db);
```

This works just fine. I can connect, authenticate, and access the database. However, this code:

```
$link = new mysqli($host, $u, $p, $db);
if(!$link){die();}
```

This results in an Access Denied for user xxxxx@localhost (using password: YES) error.

I have made used mysqli so many times, but I've never had this happen.

### Additional things I've tried

- Specifying port 3306 does not help
- Specifying the WAN IP does not help
- mysqli_connect
- 127.0.0.1

### Mysqli settings:

```
MysqlI Support => enabled
Client API library version => 5.1.54
Active Persistent Links => 0
Inactive Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
Client API header version => 5.1.54
MYSQLI_SOCKET => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysqli.allow_persistent => On => On
mysqli.default_host => no value => no value
mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306
mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value
mysqli.default_socket => no value => no value
mysqli.default_user => no value => no value
mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off
```

### Update

- MYSQL_SOCKET = MYSQLI_SOCKET
- Specifying the socket manually in the new mysqli does nothing
- Adding extension=mysqli.so to the php.ini did nothing.
- Restarting Apache after all of this did nothing.

Comment: Can you try connecting using procedural style to see if that works? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: You might also want to add this: `if ($link->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $link->connect_errno . ') '
            . $link->connect_error);
}`

Comment: @Maximus2012 Connecting that way returns a false bool.

Comment: Can you update your question with that information ?

Comment: `$link->connect_errno`?

Comment: Have you tried using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`?

Comment: Don't this might make any difference but try enclosing the connection parameters in single quote in place of double quote ? That is what I see in the examples on the php manual page.

Comment: it could easily be an ini issue, same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2024837/1816093). Each config has a different socket name section

Comment: Connect errno is 1045

Comment: 127.0.0.1 doesn't work

Comment: `$host="127.0.0.1:3306";` ?

Comment: @David Did your try it with the port like this `$link = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', $u, $p, $db, 3306);`

Comment: @Maximus unknown host error now.

Comment: @imtheman yep, still didn't work.

Comment: check your ini. I mentioned it above

Comment: I agree with @Drew it seems like the only thing it can be at this point.

Comment: I'm SSHing in right now. I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: Did you check `mysql_error()` after `mysql_select_db()` probably the issue is that you don't have access to the database.

Comment: See if some of the things mentioned here help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw

Comment: I don't see any extensions in the ini file at all. What is the proper extension for mysqli?

Comment: `php -i` from command line should show you all extension settings.

Comment: @miken32 I've updated the question with all mysqli settings

Comment: How does `MYSQLI_SOCKET => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` compare with the value for `MYSQL_SOCKET`?

Comment: @miken32 MYSQL_SOCKET => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock, MYSQLI_SOCKET => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: Well, that's my idea gone! Maybe add the mysql extension settings to your question as well?

Comment: @miken32 question has been updated.

Comment: I can't even connect to mysql through SSH with the `mysql -u user -p` command. I get the same 1045 error.